# A (Nonuniquely) Spanish Conundrum

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, geography

Spain is sitting in his room, vibing to some of his classical music. Then, his computer goes dark…

And then a prompt appears: ENTER WORD

Spain, confuzzled, enters a random word: **CLAN**.
Then music begins playing. Spain recognizes it: *La noche es para mí - Soraya*

Spain is… not happy, to say the least with it reminding him of his worst failure. 23rd!

He tried another word: **RICE**.
More music plays, and Spain is PROUD he can recognize this: *Mayéutica - Roberto Iniesta*

Again, he tries. He thinks, this will be the final time. He tries a 5 letter word: **CLASS**. The computer goes black for a moment, and then spits out:

*Breadth-First Search L1 has failed. Entering L2…*

**ERRO———**

He doesn’t recognize it, but her roommate, Sweden, does.

“*Oh my Goooooooosh, are you listening to Léonnnnn? That’s like, her best single!!! Yass, Spain!*”

Spain is not amused.

**Can you figure out the pattern behind these?**

EXTRA POINTS: Figure out how to play one of Blanca Paloma’s songs.

Comment: Madding: "Erro____" could be "Errol Flynn" or "errotica" or "erroneous" or almost anything.  What fun.